# how to get super precise waiting

Tags: android, wait, timing

I'm developing a music app, and I need to have a rhythm section. Now this section has to be able to precisely play complex beats, the only way I can think about doing it is by playing a sound file and then waiting for a certain amount of time before playing another one:

```
soundpool.play(beat_hit,1,1,1,0,0);

try{ Thread.sleep(delay); }catch(InterruptedException e){ }

soundpool.play(beat_hit,1,1,1,0,0);
```

The problem is that Thread.sleep isn't nearly as precise as I need it to be.

I read somewhere that you need to get rid of the many layers java has and go directly to the CPU using assembly language for precise timing, any idea how to do that?

Comment: This sounds something you could do with SchedulePoolThreadExecutor https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html there is somethinf over there about fixed and delay. Probably you will need a recursive function for handling uneven beats.

Comment: I could use it but I just need to be sure that its precise enough for what I need it to do.